# Netting a weighted matrix in igraph (R)

Tags: r, igraph

Is there a simple way that I'm missing to create a netted version of a simple, weighted, directed network in igraph? This is where mutual edges are replaced with a single edge carrying the difference between the weights and the direction is such that the weight is always positive. A simple example:

```
gGross <- graph_from_literal(A++B)
E(gGross)$weight <- c(12, 20)

gNet <- graph_from_literal(A+-B)
E(gNet)$weight <- c(8)
```

[image: Gross network on the left, desired net matrix on the right]

In matrix notation this would be

N_{ij} = (A_{ij} - A_{ji})_+

where the + means keep positive elements.

A good starting point would be something similar to `which_mutual` that gives the index of the return edge. I can imagine writing a long function in R but that seems likely to be slow.

Comment: I've made some progress with the last bit.

    `ends(g, E(g)[which_mutual(g)], names=FALSE)`

Gives a matrix of all mutual edges. This could be fed into an apply.

Comment: This is oh-so-nearly what I need `g2 <- as.undirected(g, mode="collapse", edge.attr.comb = function(x) x[1]-x[2])` but not sure how reliable the direction is.

Answer (score 0):

I feel I can do better than this, but I do at least have a working method. Improvements most welcome. Edited to reflect Tamás' comments and allow use of any attribute

```
nettedGraph <- function(g, col="weight") {

  if(!(col %in% edge_attr_names(g))) {
    stop(col, " not and edge attribute")
  }

  # Get a matrix of mutual edges (by vertex ids)
  me <- ends(g, E(g)[which_mutual(g)], names=FALSE)

  # Only keep one of the mutual edges
  me <- me[me[,1] < me[,2], ] 

  toDel <- vector(mode="integer", length=nrow(me))

  for (i in 1:nrow(me)) {

    # Get edge ids going each way
    e1 <- get.edge.ids(g, c(me[i,1],me[i,2]))
    e2 <- get.edge.ids(g, c(me[i,2],me[i,1]))

    weightDiff <- edge_attr(g,col, e1) - edge_attr(g,col, e2)

    if(weightDiff > 0) {
      # Update the edge we're keeping
      edge_attr(g,col, e1) <- weightDiff
      # Delete the one we're not
      toDel[i] <- e2
    } else {
      # Update the edge we're keeping
      edge_attr(g,col, e2) <- -weightDiff
      # Delete the one we're not
      toDel[i] <- e1
    }

  }

  # Now delete all the unneeded edges
  g <- g - E(g)[toDel]

  return(g)
}

set.seed(123)

g <- graph_from_literal(A-+B, B++C, A++C)
E(g)$weight <- round(runif(ecount(g),1,20))
weight0 <- E(g)$weight

gNet <- nettedGraph(g)
```

Comment: igraph's internal graph data structure is constructed in a way that removing a single edge has approximately the same time complexity as removing multiple edges. So, I would simply collect the IDs of the edges to be deleted in the `for` loops and delete them in one single batch at the end.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good tip. I might even be able to get rid of the for loop all together if I think about it.